# Commutativity in local class field theory

Tags: class-field-theory, local-field

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and $L,M$ be finite Galois extensions of $K$ such that $L\subset M$. Let $\phi_L\in Z^2(\text{Gal}(L/K),L^\times)$ such that $[\phi_L]$ is a generator of $H^2(\text{Gal}(L/K),L^\times)$, and $\phi_M\in Z^2(\text{Gal}(M/K),M^\times)$ such that $[\phi_M]^{[M:L]}=[\phi_L]$.

Then by local class field theory there exists an isomorphism: $\text{Gal}(L/K)^{\text{ab}}\cong K^\times/N_{L/K}(L^\times)$ induced by $[\phi_L]$ (I think the concrete map is $g\mapsto \prod_{h\in \text{Gal}(L/K)}\phi_L(h,g)$) 
and an isomorphism $\text{Gal}(M/K)^{\text{ab}}\cong K^\times/N_{M/K}(M^\times)$ induced by $[\phi_K]$. The question is how to prove the following diagram commutes:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}[c]{ccc}
\text{Gal}(M/K)^{\text{ab}} & \rightarrow K^\times/N_{M/K}(M^\times)\\
\downarrow & \downarrow \\
\text{Gal}(L/K)^{\text{ab}} & \rightarrow K^\times/N_{L/K}(L^\times)
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

I think it makes sense because the diagram is independent of the choice of $\phi_M$ such that  $[\phi_M]^{[M:L]}=[\phi_L]$. But I don't know how to prove it.

Thank you!

Comment: I believe that what you wrote is exactly the Nakayama map of class formation. It depends on the choice of $[\phi_M]$!! Nevertheless, your diagram commutes. Please see Neukirch, Schmidt, Wingber-cohomology of number fields, through thm 3.1.6~remarks after def 3.1.8.